# Arithmetic Coding FPAQ0 (a simple order-0 arithmetic file compressor )

Tags: c++, compression

I am trying to understand the code of fpaq0 aritmetic compressor but I am not able to fully understand it.Here is the link to the code -[fpaq0.cpp](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/fpaq0.cpp)

I am not able to understand exactly the how ct[512]['2] and cxt are working.Also I am not very much clear how decoder is working.Why before encoding every charater e.encode(0) is being called.

NOTE; I have understood the arithmetic coder presented in the link-[Data Compression with Arithmetic Encoding](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/data-compression-with-arithmetic-encodin/240169251?pgno=1)

```
  void update(int y) {
if (++ct[cxt][y] > 65534) {
  ct[cxt][0] >>= 1;
  ct[cxt][1] >>= 1;
}
if ((cxt+=cxt+y) >= 512)
  cxt=1;
}
   // Assume a stationary order 0 stream of 9-bit symbols
int p() const {
 return 4096*(ct[cxt][1]+1)/(ct[cxt][0]+ct[cxt][1]+2);
}
inline void Encoder::encode(int y) {

// Update the range
const U32 xmid = x1 + ((x2-x1) >> 12) * predictor.p();
assert(xmid >= x1 && xmid < x2);
if (y)
 x2=xmid;
else
x1=xmid+1;
predictor.update(y);

// Shift equal MSB's out
while (((x1^x2)&0xff000000)==0) {
putc(x2>>24, archive);
x1<<=8;
x2=(x2<<8)+255;
}
}

inline int Encoder::decode() {

// Update the range
const U32 xmid = x1 + ((x2-x1) >> 12) * predictor.p();
assert(xmid >= x1 && xmid < x2);
int y=0;
if (x<=xmid) {
 y=1;
 x2=xmid;
}
else
x1=xmid+1;
predictor.update(y);

// Shift equal MSB's out
while (((x1^x2)&0xff000000)==0) {
x1<<=8;
x2=(x2<<8)+255;
int c=getc(archive);
if (c==EOF) c=0;
x=(x<<8)+c;
}
return y;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant section of code?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic added the code

Comment: I'm still a little unclear about which part of the code you are asking about

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic how the update is working

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic How the probabilty is being calculated .What model is being used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fpaq0 is a file compressor which uses an order-0 bitwise model for modeling and uses 12-bits carry-less arithmetic coder for entropy coding stage. `ct[512][2]` stores counters for each contexts to compute symbol probabilities. The context (order-0 in fpaq0) is calculated with partial bits with a leading one (to simplify calculations).

For more easy explanation, let's skip EOF symbol for now. Order-0 context calculated as follow without EOF symbol (simplified):

```cpp
// Full byte encoding
int cxt = 1; // context starts with leading one
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  // Encoding part
  int y = ReadNextBit();
  int p = GetProbability(ctx);
  EncodeBit(y, p);

  // Model updating
  UpdateCounter(cxt, y); // Update related counter
  cxt = (cxt << 1) | y; // shift left and insert new bit
}
```

For decoding, context is used without EOF symbol like following (simplified):

```
// Full byte decoding
int cxt = 1; // context starts with leading one
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  // Decoding part
  int p = GetProbability(ctx);
  int y = DecodeBit(p);
  WriteBit(y);

  // Model updating
  UpdateCounter(cxt, y); // Update related counter
  cxt = (cxt << 1) | y; // shift left and insert new bit
}
```

fpaq0 is designed as a streaming compressor. Meaning that it doesn't need to know exact length of the input stream. So, the question how decoder should know when to stop? EOF symbol used exactly for that. While encoding every single byte, a zero bit is encoded as a flag to indicate there is more data to follow. One indicates we reached the end of stream. So, decoder knows when to stop. That's the reason why our context model is 9-bits (EOF flag + 8 bits data).

Now, the last part: probability calculation. fpaq0 uses just counts of past symbols under order-0 context to calculate final probability.

```
n0 = count of 0
n1 = count of 1
p = n1 / (n0 + n1)
```

There are two implementation details that should be addressed: counter overflow and division by zero.

Counter overflow is addressed by halving both counts when they reach a threshold. Since, we're dealing with `p`, it makes sense.

Division by zero is addressed by inserting one into formula for each variables. So,

```
p = (n1 + 1) / ((n0 + 1) + (n1 + 1))
```